# Song are not detectioned in gracenote SDK. Some are detected and some are not

Tags: gracenote

I have tried to detect many songs but some are detected and some are not, There is any issue in GNSDK? Is there any other library related to this? Please help to resolve issue.

Comment: please add some more info .. what kind of detect you are doing ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out for Jplayer .That is good .Refer http://jplayer.org/

Comment: This comment is totally unrelated to the question asked